# XML parsing speed up. PHP

Tags: php, xml, performance, algorithm

I'm here to ask about some concepts that can make this process faster:

```
foreach($xml->results->concepts->concept as $value2){//This is the original game.
    $total_concepts++;
    foreach($xml1->results->concepts->concept as $value1){//This is similar game. 
        $total_similar_concepts++;
        if(strcmp($value2->name, $value1->name)==0){
            $comparisons++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm comparing each 'concept' of the original game to each 'concept' of each 'similar' games.

This algorithm takes about 11.6 seconds on average to complete.  Is there something I can do to make this run faster?  I was thinking that perhaps parsing it as xml wasn't the best I could do.

Comment: You algorithms time complexity is O(n^2). Thats why it is slow.

Comment: How long are the concepts? Is using a database an option? If you are dealing with datasets, parsing xml with php will usually be slower than using a sql database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML parsing is very unlikely the reason for your problem. If it has to do with XML that it's probably I/O, meaning that it takes to long to fetch data from disk.

What you are doing is combining all elements in $xml with all elements in $xml2 which is an O(n^2) complexity problem. You can try to reduce complexity by making use of a hashmap, which is easy in php because you got associative arrays which are essentially hashmaps:

```
foreach($xml->results->concepts->concept as $value2) {
  $total_concepts++;
  $map[(string)$value2->name] = true;
}
foreach($xml1->results->concepts->concept as $value1) {
  $total_similar_concepts++;
  if (isset($map[(string)$value1->name]))
    $comparisions++;
}
```

In best case this gives you O(2n) complexity, much better than the previous version.

Comment: I'm not sure what mapping here means.  And this code seems to yield different results from what my previous code did.  

Could you help me understand it a bit better?

Comment: @Adola: Hashmaps aka Hashtables is a concept for fast access to non-continuous indexed data structures. Read more on it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. Actually the concept is quite simple, but I can't find a simple explanation on google. Feel free to ask a seperate questions on how hash maps work if you have trouble understanding. I'll give you a simpler explanation if I find it. And please elaborate on how the results are different.

Comment: Yeah, $comparisions never gets iterated in this version.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure I get how this works just fine, now I'm confused as to why it doesn't work. 

It's a pretty simple and elegant solution, but I'm still unsure of why it's not working.

Comment: So, I just did a test, and this isn't yielding anything. 


    foreach($xml->results->concepts->concept as $value2){
  $map[$value2->name] = true;
  if(isset($map[$value2->name])){
   echo "TEST!";
                }
    }

Shouldn't it under every situation always print TEST! ?  
I mean, it's being set, then being asked if was set.

Comment: well yes, it should. What datatype is $value2->name? Please try casting it to a string: `if (isset($map[(string)$value1->name]))`. Do this it all locations where you access `$...->name`

Comment: foreach($xml->results->concepts->concept as $value2){
  $total_concepts++;
  $map[(string)$value2->name] = true;
  foreach($xml1->results->concepts->concept as $value1){
   if ($map[(string)$value1->name]){
    $comparisons++;
   }
  }
 }


I actually did that, and got some odd answers: 

Original example: 
12
4
2
1
0
1
18
54
66
82
55
This version: 
1363
431
144
16
0
16
2025
6627
6867
8580
6787
4287

All I did was echo $comparisons;

Comment: Why do you have the loops nested again? You are not supposed to. I updated my answer to reflect the latest findings. Try with that version again.

Comment: Gracious, My misunderstanding was that I assume it was nested.  This is brilliant, from 11 seconds to .1.  It seems it was certainly file-access.  Thank you very much, i've learned quite a valuable lesson!